# How to select element loaded dynamically with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Since there are parts of the page that are the same for all pages, I wish I could load them dynamically, so that I can edit them just once. I need, for example, to load a sidebar and a navbar.

After being loaded, I need to store some elements in those external pages in variables so that I can call them later, for example, to animate them, manipulate them and so on.

I thought that I only needed to select the class or the id but it seems not enough.

```
<!-- navbar.html -->
<div id="navbar-content">
    <div id="element1"></div>
    <div id="element2"></div>
    <div id="element3"></div>
</div>

<!-- index.html -->
$( '#navbar' ).load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *' );
$( '#sidebar' ).load( 'sidebar.html #sidebar-content > *' );

var element1 = $( '#element1' ),
    element2 = $( '#element2' ),
    element3 = $( '#element3' );

console.log( 'element1' );
```

The console returns:

```
Object { length: 0, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → products.html, selector: "#element1" }
```

which means that the console has returned nothing.

How can I select elements loaded dynamically, if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `complete` callback of `load()` if you are initalizing plugins.

```
$( '#navbar' ).load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *' , function(){
     // new html now exists in #navbar, run code here that manipulates the html
     // alse "this" is #navbar
    $(this).find('.someSelector').doSomething();
});
```

An alternate way to set this up is to create a function and pass that function as reference to load()

```
function initNavbar(){
    $(this).find('.someSelector').doSomething();
}

$( '#navbar' ).load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *', initNavbar);
```

If all you are doing is adding event handlers you can do that using event delegation anywhere in your code

Reference: [load() API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Is this possible to bind the same callback to two load function? `$el1.load('el1.html', callback);   $el2.load('el2.html', callback)`

Comment: can use `$.when($el1.load(...), $el2.load( ..) ).done(function(){ /* both are done now*/})`

Comment: but yes, could use same load callback handler if that suits your needs.

Comment: it does not work `$.when( $('#main-navbar').load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *' ), $('#sidebar').load( 'sidebar.html #sidebar-content > *' )).done( loadCallback );` it still returns undefined variables

Comment: Define the variables within $.when. You can not continue with approach shown in the question due to asynchrnous nature of ajax

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $('#navbar').load('navbar.html #navbar-content > *', function(){
         var element1 = $( '#element1' ),
         element2 = $( '#element2' ),
         element3 = $( '#element3' );

         console.log(element1.text());
   });

   $('#sidebar').load('sidebar.html #sidebar-content > *', function (){
         //or here
   });
```

In this way, you will access the elements after the loading is complete.

Comment: Is this possible only within the function?

Comment: In the function is the only place where you're 100% certain the content was actually already loaded.

Comment: @erkaner I'd rather not, because in this way I am bind to work within the function and it may be possible that other plugins that needs to call those elements but must be called outside the function won't work.

Comment: @dcdeiv your last comment doesn't make sense without some context

Comment: @charlietfl Well, in the navbar there is a button that opens a sidebar which is loaded dynamically too thorough ajax. So I repeat the same process for the sidebar, and I have a plugin which needs to select that button that unfortunately it does not see because it's not in it's function.

Comment: @dcdev 2 ways around that ...nest the load calls or use `$.when`

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the variables directly after the `.load()` statements, so it's possible that the elements aren't actually loaded yet. You will have to wait until you're sure the content was loaded before assigning the variables.

The `.load()` method accepts a callback function that will fire when it's done. That would be a good place to start:

```
$( '#navbar' ).load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *' , function() {
    var element1 = $( '#element1' ),
        element2 = $( '#element2' ),
        element3 = $( '#element3' );

    console.log( element1 );
});
```

This would also work and is a little more reusable:

```
$( '#navbar' ).load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *' , myCallback);

function myCallback() {
    var element1 = ... etc
}
```

Comment: `console.log( 'element1' )` will simply output that string

Comment: Yeah, just edited that. I copied it straight from the question without thinking :P

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the elements within the callback function for `load()`.  This will ensure that the elements you are trying to select exist in the DOM.

```
$( '#navbar' ).load( 'navbar.html #navbar-content > *', function(){
    var element1 = $( '#element1' ),
    element2 = $( '#element2' ),
    element3 = $( '#element3' );
});
```